# Is there a substitute for `HttpProperties` in spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to update my existing code base to Spring Boot 2.3.0. In my existing code base which is a library and is used by many other projects, There's a class that uses `HttpProperties`, and this class has been removed in Spring Boot 2.3.0. There was no warning or deprecation in previous versions.
My code is as below.

```
import static org.springframework.core.Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class FilterConfiguration {

    private final MyProperties properties;

    private final HttpProperties.Encoding httpEncodingProperties;

    @Autowired
    public FilterConfiguration(MyProperties properties, HttpProperties httpProperties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.httpEncodingProperties = httpProperties.getEncoding();
    }

    @Bean
    public OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
        OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter filter = new OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding(httpEncodingProperties.getCharset().name());
        filter.setForceEncoding(httpEncodingProperties.isForce());
        filter.setOrder(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return filter;
    }
}
```

I just want to upgrade my project to 2.3.0 without breaking any code base that uses this library, but I am stuck because I can't find a replacement for the class `HttpProperties`.
Any help on how to upgrade this code piece to Spring Boot 2.3.0.

Comment: You didn't share your YML file but basically you could now configure encoding by setting `server.servlet.encoding` instead of `spring.http.encoding` and access it via `ServerProperties`. See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18827

Answer (score 0):

Some http-related classes were moved, see [Move spring.http.* configuration properties namespace](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18827)

Encoding is now available as org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.Encoding

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.Encoding;
....
Encoding encoding = new Encoding();
encoding.getCharset();
encoding.isForce();
```

That seems to cover your usecase.

Other changes are mentioned on that issue:

> ```
> spring.http.encoding.* -> server.servlet.encoding.*
> spring.http.log-request-details -> spring.mvc.log-request-details (Spring MVC) or spring.codec.log-request-details (Spring WebFlux)
> spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper -> spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper
> ```